# Reading data from csv file and putting in 2D float vector such that column of csv file is row of 2D vector

Tags: c++, csv

I am stuck with an very complicated problem. I am presently working on making parallel RMSProp optimization algorithm for a class project. I want to test my algorithm with real data https://www.kaggle.com/code/prasadperera/the-boston-housing-dataset
The sample code to read data from csv file is below:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::ifstream infile("housing.csv");

    // Check if file is open
    if (!infile.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "Error opening file\n";
        return 1;
    }

    std::string line;
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> data; // 2D vector to store data

    // Read data line by line
    while (std::getline(infile, line)) {
        std::stringstream ss(line);
        std::vector<std::string> row;
        std::string cell;

        // Read each cell of the row and add to vector
        while (std::getline(ss, cell, ',')) {
            row.push_back(cell);
        }

        // Add row to 2D vector
        data.push_back(row);
    }

    // Print the data
    for (const auto& row : data) {
        for (const auto& cell : row) {
            std::cout << cell << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    infile.close(); // Close the file
    return 0;
}
```

I want to put this value in a 2D float vector such that each column of csv file becomes a row of my 2D vector.
The last column of my csv file goes into another 1D vector.
It is really sad for me to say that I tried everything but could not getting it working at all since I am new to programming.
It would be really great help if someone can help me on this or suggest some way.

*Edit*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    // Open the CSV file for reading
    ifstream infile("housing.csv");
    // Check if file is open
    if (!infile.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "Error opening file\n";
        return 1;
    }

    std::string line;
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> data; // 2D vector to store data
    std::vector<std::string> somewhere;

    bool first_line = true;
    // Read each line of the CSV file

    while (std::getline(infile, line)) {
        std::stringstream ss(line);
        std::vector<std::string> work;

        std::string cell;
        // Read each cell of the line and add to working vector
        while (std::getline(ss, cell, ',')) {
            work.push_back(cell);
        }

        // last item goes to somewhere
        somewhere.push_back(work.back());
        // remove last item from working vector
        work.pop_back();

    // set data size if first line of input
        if (first_line)
        {
            data.resize(work.size());
            first_line = false;
        }

    // Add working vector to data
        for (size_t i = 0; i < work.size(); ++i){
            data[i].push_back(work[i]);
        }
       
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < data[i].size(); j++) {
            std::cout << data[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
Job ID is 45232337
Running on host r05r08n02
Working directory is /panfs/pfs.local/work/i2s/Adam
The following processors are allocated to this job:
r05r08n02
Start: 2023-05-10_02:03:37
Stop: 2023-05-10_02:03:40
```

The data in housing.csv looks like below:

```
0.00632  18.00   2.310  0  0.5380  6.5750  65.20  4.0900   1  296.0  15.30 396.90   4.98  24.00
 0.02731   0.00   7.070  0  0.4690  6.4210  78.90  4.9671   2  242.0  17.80 396.90   9.14  21.60
 0.02729   0.00   7.070  0  0.4690  7.1850  61.10  4.9671   2  242.0  17.80 392.83   4.03  34.70
 0.03237   0.00   2.180  0  0.4580  6.9980  45.80  6.0622   3  222.0  18.70 394.63   2.94  33.40
 0.06905   0.00   2.180  0  0.4580  7.1470  54.20  6.0622   3  222.0  18.70 396.90   5.33  36.20
 0.02985   0.00   2.180  0  0.4580  6.4300  58.70  6.0622   3  222.0  18.70 394.12   5.21  28.70
 0.08829  12.50   7.870  0  0.5240  6.0120  66.60  5.5605   5  311.0  15.20 395.60  12.43  22.90
 0.14455  12.50   7.870  0  0.5240  6.1720  96.10  5.9505   5  311.0  15.20 396.90  19.15  27.10
```

** Edit **

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::ifstream file("housing.csv");
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> data;
    std::string line;

    while (std::getline(file, line)) {
        std::vector<std::string> row;
        std::stringstream ss(line);
        std::string cell;

        while (std::getline(ss, cell, '\t')) {
            row.push_back(cell);
        }

        data.push_back(row);
    }

    // Print the data
    for (auto& row : data) {
        for (auto& cell : row) {
            std::cout << cell << '\t';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
Start: 2023-05-10_02:51:22
 0.00632  18.00   2.310  0  0.5380  6.5750  65.20  4.0900   1  296.0  15.30 396.90   4.98  24.00    
 0.02731   0.00   7.070  0  0.4690  6.4210  78.90  4.9671   2  242.0  17.80 396.90   9.14  21.60    
 0.02729   0.00   7.070  0  0.4690  7.1850  61.10  4.9671   2  242.0  17.80 392.83   4.03  34.70    
 0.03237   0.00   2.180  0  0.4580  6.9980  45.80  6.0622   3  222.0  18.70 394.63   2.94  33.40    
 0.06905   0.00   2.180  0  0.4580  7.1470  54.20  6.0622   3  222.0  18.70 396.90   5.33  36.20    
 0.02985   0.00   2.180  0  0.4580  6.4300  58.70  6.0622   3  222.0  18.70 394.12   5.21  28.70    
 0.08829  12.50   7.870  0  0.5240  6.0120  66.60  5.5605   5  311.0  15.20 395.60  12.43  22.90    
 0.14455  12.50   7.870  0  0.5240  6.1720  96.10  5.9505   5  311.0  15.20 396.90  19.15  27.10    
 0.21124  12.50   7.870  0  0.5240  5.6310 100.00  6.0821   5  311.0  15.20 386.63  29.93  16.50    
 0.17004  12.50   7.870  0  0.5240  6.0040  85.90  6.5921   5  311.0  15.20 386.71  17.10  18.90    
 0.22489  12.50   7.870  0  0.5240  6.3770  94.30  6.3467   5  311.0  15.20 392.52  20.45  15.00    
 0.11747  12.50   7.870  0  0.5240  6.0090  82.90  6.2267   5  311.0  15.20 396.90  13.27  18.90    
 0.09378  12.50   7.870  0  0.5240  5.8890  39.00  5.4509   5  311.0  15.20 390.50  15.71  21.70    
 0.6
```

Comment: Did you write the code you show? If not, then what is your own attempt? What have you tried? What problems do you have with your own attempt?

Comment: And perhaps all you need to learn is about the [`std::stod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) function?

Comment: Thank you @Someprogrammerdude for your response. My attempts got messed up. Trying it fresh again. I though that I should save the values as i am reading in a 2D vector of float and then just transpose but it is not working. Providing me any link would be great help.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
// Read data line by line
bool first_line = true;
while (std::getline(infile, line)) {
    std::stringstream ss(line);
    std::vector<std::string> work;

    std::string cell;
    // Read each cell of the line and add to working vector
    while (std::getline(ss, cell, ',')) {
        work.push_back(cell);
    }

    // last item goes to somewhere
    somewhere.push_back(work.back());
    // remove last item from working vector
    work.pop_back();

    // set data size if first line of input
    if (first_line)
    {
        data.resize(work.size());
        first_line = false;
    }

    // Add working vector to data
    for (size_t i = 0; i < work.size(); ++i)
        data[i].push_back(work[i]);
}
```

This is untested code. There is also very little error checking in the code, in particular it assumes that all your lines have the same number of data items.

Comment: Thank you @john for this great help. I am working on testing the code.

Comment: There is some minor error i am still doing .@john I have edited the question. Some how i am not able to print the values.

Comment: @Manu Your code assumes that the data is comma separated, but the data you posted is space separated.

Comment: @Manu CSV stands for *comma separated values*, but the data on that web site is not in that format (despite what it claims).

Comment: @Manu In fact look at the python code from the web site `read_csv('../input/housing.csv', header=None, delimiter=r"\s+", names=column_names)` See the `delimiter` is set to `\s+` that means the delimiter is one or more spaces, not commas at all.

Comment: I tried using '\t' but it is not printing @john

Comment: @Manu You need to rewrite that portion of the code, you cannot use `getline` because it only works in the case of a single delimiter between values (whatever that delimiter might be). The python code from the website makes it clear that there could multiple whitespace characters between each data item. Since you are reading floating point values I suggest you change your `vector<vector<string>>` to `vector<vector<double>>` and just read the floating point values directly.

Comment: Hi @john, I tested with a sample code shown in EDIT2. The getline thing works with this data if we put '\t'. I am not sure what more modifications are required?

Comment: @Manu Well the data in edit2 **appears** to be tab delimited because all the columns line up perfectly. But the data in the first edit does not appear to be tab delimited because in that case the columns do not line up. I don't know though because maybe the data got scrambled when you posted it. If you have code that is not working then you have to debug it to find out why it is not working. Only then will you know how to fix it. Not really sure what more I can do to help.

Answer (score 0):

Usually I would have a lot of qualms about the inefficiency of reading a file twice. However, it might help you in this instance, because it would allow you to determine the number of rows and columns first, set up an array of doubles and then read directly into it.

Also, CSV files tend to contain "mixed data" - for example, your file includes text headers above the numeric data. However, as long as you know the number of header lines you can skip the appropriate number of lines.

So, if you are prepared to put up with a "read-file-twice/read-directly-into-doubles" solution then the following might help you.

Note that there are some qualifiers. The numeric data array must be rectangular, not ragged. There must be no missing data (strings would be inevitable if there were). There must be an identifiable separator (see below).

As others have commented, your file is not a CSV file (well, according to my definition anyway), because the data is separated by whitespace, not a comma or similar.

I have changed the data file by adding commas. If you want to read the original file then you will have to adjust the read statements and number-of-columns acquirer as necessary.

Datafile:

```
A,    CRIM,    ZN,  INDUS,  CHAS,    NOX,     RM,   AGE,     DIS,  RAD,    TAX
0, 0.00632,  18.0,   2.31,     0,  0.538,  6.575,  65.2,  4.0900,    1,  296.0
1, 0.02731,   0.0,   7.07,     0,  0.469,  6.421,  78.9,  4.9671,    2,  242.0
2, 0.02729,   0.0,   7.07,     0,  0.469,  7.185,  61.1,  4.9671,    2,  242.0
3, 0.03237,   0.0,   2.18,     0,  0.458,  6.998,  45.8,  6.0622,    3,  222.0
4, 0.06905,   0.0,   2.18,     0,  0.458,  7.147,  54.2,  6.0622,    3,  222.0
```

Sample code:

```
#include <iostream>                         
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

vector< vector<double> > getdata( const string &filename, char separator = ',', int headerlines = 0 )
{

   // *** First pass: quick read to establish number of rows and columns
   ifstream in( filename );
   string line;
   getline( in, line );
   int nrows = 1;
   int ncols = count( line.begin(), line.end(), separator ) + 1;     // if separator present, count to get ncols
   while( getline( in, line ) ) nrows++;
   nrows -= headerlines;

   // *** Second pass: set up a float array and read directly into it (remember the headerlines)
   vector< vector<double> > result( nrows, vector<double>( ncols ) );
   in.close();
   in.open( filename );

   char dummy;
   for ( int i = 0; i < headerlines; i++ ) getline( in, line );      // skip header lines
   for ( int i = 0; i < nrows; i++ )                                 // ith row
   {
      in >> result[i][0];                                            // first item
      for ( int j = 1; j < ncols; j++ ) in >> dummy >> result[i][j]; // then comma and item pairs
   }

   return result;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------

int main()
{
   auto data = getdata( "housing.csv", ',', 1 );
   for ( auto &row : data )
   {
      for ( auto e : row ) cout << e << '\t';
      cout << '\n';
   }
}
```

As your data is actually a mix of ints and doubles (I think), then an alternative approach is to create a struct with precisely those fields and overload the << operator to read in a line containing an object of precisely that type.